# What does Visions of Jesus and Mary Mean to Muslims?

Tags: christianity

I have seen a couple of vidoes/documentaries where devoted Muslim have seen visions of Jesus or Mary. They were touched by Jesus and many of them converted to Christianity. These people speak openly about their encounters.

I am also aware that the Prophet said, who ever see me in a dream has indeed seen me because Shaitan can not come in his form. The prophet forbade though to share such dreams with other people.

I also know that Shia Muslim have strong belief in their Imams and claim they they can fulfill their prayers. They cite a number of incidences where an Imams have miraculously cured uncurable diseases when they were called upon or simply they appeared in a vision and cured the person?

My question is, Since there are a lot of vision where a Muslim see Jesus and is touched by him but virutually non where a non Muslim sees the prophet Image? Does this in anyway qualify that one religion is more truthful than the other? [video1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-jhtxqpAQQE), [video2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rrt0cAqJURk), [vidoe3](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V9LLNdeO-lM)

Comment: It's hard to verify whether they are telling the truth or not. And even if truth, it is hard to verify the cause of the dream and whether the dream tells truth or not.

Answer (score 3):

Contrasted with Ex-Muslims who say that they experience visions and miracles after accepting Christianity, Ex-Christians who convert to Islam usually do so after finding the answers to life (Why are we here? Who is God? What as human beings are we supposed to do here on Earth? etc).

Once in a while, someone is lead to Islam after a dream as well. Here are a few:

- [Jesus told me to accept Islam](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C1nmMuuaCy4)
- [Christian dreams about Muhammad (pbuh) and converts](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0wuFFX3M0oY)
- [Another conversion after a dream](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w12pXKzQX0U)

The Question is whether or not these experiences can be held as a proof for the masses?  If it can, then there would be a problem determining the authenticity of each one of these  "personal miracles" and then we would somehow have to combine a bunch of contradictory experiences into one universal truth.

I personally do believe that such experiences, while being accompanied with reason, may be used as evidence leading one to the Ultimate Truth. But only on a individual level. One man cannot preach to his community using a single dream as his primary foundation for his faith. And i would disregard any dream that leads me to accept a belief that does not make sense.

*Note: many of these Ex-Muslims show little to no knowledge of Islam, and their ignorance indicates that they in fact were never Muslims to begin with. (for example: a former Muslim claiming to have found Jesus (pbuh) for the first time, even though he is mentioned in the Quran. [And Sometimes these Ex-Muslims make enormous blunders like this, while telling their conversion story.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vT2ImYJsLco)*